# Upload image to imgur using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load an image from imgur on the same page, without reloading. I used `ajax` to perform that.

I tried doing it without `ajax`, and it works fine, but it reloads the page. So I added the following ajax code, and now the image doesn't load at all. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function onsuccess(response, status) {
    $("#onsuccessmsg").html("Status :<b>" + status + '</b><br><br>Response Data :<div id="msg" style="border:5px solid #CCC;padding:15px;">' + response + '</div>');
  }
  $("#uploadform").on('submit', function() {
    var options = {
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      success: onsuccess
    };
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform">
  <input type="file" name="img" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
  <br/>
  <br/>Message :
  <div id="onsuccessmsg" style="border:5px solid #CCC;padding:15px;"></div>
</form>
```

Here's the php code:

#### upload.php

```
<?php
$img=$_FILES['img'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    if($img['name']==''){  
        echo "<h2>An Image Please.</h2>";
    }else{
        $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
        $client_id="my-id";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
        $timeout = 30;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);
        $pms = json_decode($out,true);
        $url=$pms['data']['link'];
        if($url!=""){
            echo "<h2>Uploaded Without Any Problem</h2>";
            echo "<img src='$url'/>";
        }else{
            echo "<h2>There's a Problem</h2>";
            echo $pms['data']['error'];  
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

**Update**

Here's an image of: AJAX request / response

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's console?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: Click F12 to reveal the developer tools. There is a Network tab. Open that up and then try to upload a file.

Comment: Should I post an image of the results?

Comment: No - you should analyze the results to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I'm a real newby in ajax. The results are gibrish to me. Would you be able to please help me get the answer?

Comment: Edit your post to add the image. I'll try to help.

Comment: Ok. Just added the image

Comment: Click on the upload.php and you will see the request and the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) die('No direct Access');
$img=$_FILES['img'];
    if($img['name']==''){  
        echo "<h2>An Image Please.</h2>";
    }else{
        $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
        $client_id="my-id";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
        $timeout = 30;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);
        $pms = json_decode($out,true);
        $url=$pms['data']['link'];
        if($url!=""){
            echo "<h2>Uploaded Without Any Problem</h2>";
            echo "<img src='$url'/>";
        }else{
            echo "<h2>There's a Problem</h2>";
            echo $pms['data']['error'];  
        } 
    }
?>
```

you dont need

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

in upload.php