# Error part in jQuery is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I build following `JavaScript` part and everything works fine. But I'm not sure if the code is completely right. Because in my script I only use `success: function()` but I don't use error. Is it a MUST to have error in a jQuery AJAX call?

Currently I'm catching the errors in my php controller function and echo them in the success part.

```
 $(document)
     .ready(function() {
         var groupName = '';
         var groupid = '';

         $(".grp")
             .click(function() {
                 $('.text-danger')
                     .html('');
                 groupName = $(this)
                     .data('groupname');
                 groupid = $(this)
                     .attr('id');
                 $('.text')
                     .html(groupName);
                 $('#dataModal')
                     .modal({
                         show: true
                     });
             });

         jQuery(".grpval")
             .click(function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                     headers: {
                         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
                             .attr('content')
                     }
                 , });
                 jQuery.ajax({
                     url: "{{ route('request_group') }}"
                     , method: 'post'
                     , data: {
                         'Gruppe': groupid
                     }
                     , success: function(data) {
                         if (typeof data.successsuccess != 'undefined') {
                             jQuery('.alert-success')
                                 .show();
                             jQuery('.alert-success')
                                 .html('<p>' + data.successsuccess + '</p>');
                             $('#dataModal')
                                 .modal('toggle');
                             window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                         } else if (typeof data.successdberror != 'undefined') {
                             jQuery('.alert-danger')
                                 .show();
                             jQuery('.alert-danger')
                                 .html('<p>' + data.successdberror + '</p>');
                             $('#dataModal')
                                 .modal('toggle');
                             window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                         } else {
                             jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, value) {
                                 jQuery('.alert-danger')
                                     .show();
                                 jQuery('.alert-danger')
                                     .html('<p>' + value + '</p>');
                                 $('#dataModal')
                                     .modal('toggle');
                                 window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                             });
                         }
                     }
                 });
             });
     });
```

EDIT: Here is the function from my Controller:

```
   public function setGroupRequest(Request $request){

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Gruppe' => [new ValidRequest]
    ]);

    $groupid = $request->input('Gruppe');

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }

    try{
        $groups_request = new GroupRequest();
        $groups_request->idgroups = $groupid;
        $groups_request->iduser = Auth::id();
        $groups_request->request_active = 1;
        $groups_request->save();

        $db_status = 'success';
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $db_status = 'error';
    }

    if($db_status == 'success'){
        return response()->json(['successsuccess'=>'Record is successfully added']);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['successdberror'=>'DB Error! Values could not be saved.']);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: _Is it a MUST to have error in a jQuery AJAX call?_ No. and _echo them in the success part._ IMHO It's bad design

Comment: how Should i redesign my code? Can you give me a Little tip/Hint?

Comment: error function is must in every ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error handling is required as you never know different things on the internet might result in failure of request for example,

- Network failure.
- Lost database connection
- Unauthorised access/access denied
- Any variable being not defined

There is nothing wrong in your way of writing `PHP` error in `success`, but writing it in `$ajax` `error` callback function is preferred as it helps in separating `error & success logic`.

In fact you can add a jquery `error` callback function as well to your `$ajax` which will handle all the errors originating from above mentioned internet failures.

You can add `error` function, which will receive any type of error coming from backend.

```
jQuery.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('request_group') }}",
          method: 'data: {
                'Gruppe': groupid
          },
          success: function(data) {
           //code here
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
              //error handling
          }
      })
```

**In your PHP file,**

```
if ($query) {
   echo "success"; //whatever you want to show on success.
} else {
   die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")); //Throw an error on failure
}
```

This way you can catch PHP error as well as any internet Network errors in your jquery ajax.

Comment: Okay, everthing what is now in my success function can stay their, no change? But what exactly is $query in the php Part? Thank you

Comment: query to your database.

Comment: I edit my text above, now you can also see my Controller. Do I have to change the last return response "successdberror" with your "die(header("HTTP..."))"? Would that be correct?

Comment: Okay, I have changed my code and it works! Thank you! But I have a few questions. In added a picture in my text above. You can see that I receive now a POST error in the javascript console. Is it correct? And currently i'm printing the exception message which gives me back only error. How can I edit this text in my Controller? 404 is Not Found Error but is this really correct? Because he finds the request route, when it comes to an error, this error would based on a db error.

Comment: `jqXHR.statusText` is the default output format, no problem in that.
I am not sure if you can edit your error text format in header, you can try out though and let me know as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658278/5648253